# How to retrieve data table record to datagriview order by invoiceno

Tags: vb.net

```
LoadRec = DbSelect("Select * from tblInvoicedeteils  where InvoiceNo= " & No & "")

If LoadRec.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView2.Show.item
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: What is the actual problem? Did you getting an exception or some unexpected behaviour?

Comment: You're probably looking for `DataGridView2.Datasource = LoadRec`, but it's hard to say for sure with such a vague question.